# Why does my SQL query always returns the same output?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services, web

I made a page where users can register. For some reason, the code that is supposed to check if the email isn't already used. Isn't working.

You can assume that the connection to the database is good. As the user can register when this piece is out commented.

```
        @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'USERAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

        if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'")) {
          echo "<p id=\"signup_confirmed\">This e-mail is already in use, please try again with another e-mail.</p>";
          exit;
        }
```

edit:

I used the mysqli extension that comes with php itself. The thing is, this used to work on previous versions. But for some reason it doesn't any more.

The code I used to check if the query send more than 0 rows also didn't work.

Comment: the semi-colon in `WHERE email = '$email';` <= is an end of statement character for one thing; remove it. Plus, you need to show us more code. you're not doing anything actually and missing an important function. You need to loop over the query. We also don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with.

Comment: your `if()` is just checking if your query successfully executed, not if it returned a row. So even 0 rows returned would result in a successful query.

Comment: show declaration of this method: $db->query(

Comment: @m0rtiis Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string, I get the same error when echoing the amount of rows after using "->num_rows"

Comment: This is open to SQL injection; use a prepared statement for this. Deleted databases happen because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'")) {
```

Yeah right, that will always return TRUE as long as the query has no syntax errors and you are connected to the database, even if no rows are returned. Hence the issue you are facing.

You have to check for number of rows returned, not whether if the query was successful or not, so your check is wrong.

1. Execute the query.
2. Check whether the query returned **[any rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)**.

Comment: I get a "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" when I try to echo the amount of rows I get. I looked at the manual link you send. Still gives me the error after copying the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

What I would personally do is define the error message as a variable then echo the variable in the HTML:

PHP:

```
if ($db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email';")) {
      $errMsg = 'Email is taken, please use another'
      exit;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h1> <?php echo $errMsg; ?> </h1>
```

In this case, you could use elseif for each possible error such as 'Password too short' etc... and just set your $errMsg = ' x is too short, must be between 4-16 characters' etc...

This may or may not work for you, depending on how you have scripted this solution, but I have found that this style has worked well for me at least in scenarios like this.

Also, if you are keeping this php script separate from the HTML, you can just include this validation script, simply by putting this at the top of your html document:

```
<?php require ' PATH TO SCRIPT '; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE email = '$email'"
```

Comment: interesting.. answer done. it helps (despite of question quality). why downvotes so regular? :)

Comment: I can try to give one reason of why this answer can be down-voted. This query does not change anything or help with anything. Its still the same result for the OP even if they use this query. We can't say that username is not there just by checking if the query executed or not. So the answer needs other changes not a query change. Then the OP says that `did it for me` which is again incorrect. It just can't. So for future readers it can confuse them into thinking that this is the solution when it is not. Lack of understanding by the OP doesn't mean it's correct.